# Immunity Debugger

Tags: reverse-engineering

Сказали в виде задания сделать
https://forum.reverse4you.org/t/malware-analysis-tutorial-19-anatomy-of-infected-driver-ximera/278

Вкратце, есть вирусный файл "max++", С помощью Immunity Debugger запускаем его и получаем зараженный файл(он заражает рандомный драйвер), не суть, через мучения почти все было выполнено, но проблема в чем, в конце сказано, что нужно открыть зараженный файл с помощью Immunity Debugger, а файл то заражен, в результате IMM не хочет справляться и...  [image: Вылезает такая ошибка]
Все варианты решения, которые нашел в интернете относятся к Olly Debugger, [пример решения, которое вообще не понял](http://www.reversing.be/article.php?story=2006102413541932&mode=print)

Нет ли у кого идей, как можно обойти проблему? В задании есть пометка

> Вам нужно отладить IMM и перезаписать некоторые его инструкции для того чтобы сделать его рабочим когда будет происходить ошибка сегментации памяти

Но как это сделать?

Comment: На всякий случай: Immunity Debugger - это доработанный напильником OllyDbg. Скорее всего все решения подходящие для OllyDbg 1.1 подойдут и для Immunity Debugger.